# jQuery Select all classes under ParentClass with ParticularClass name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several classes named "ParentClass" and for each parent class I want to modify css for any inner html tags with a class of "ParticularClass".  How do you do this in jQuery?

```
<elemnent class="ParentClass">
   ... <element /><element /><element /><element /><element />
                            <element class="ParticularClass">Deeply Hidden</element>
</element>

<element class="ParentClass">
    <element class="ParticularClass" />
    <element class="ParticularClass" ?
</element>
```

I'm basically getting the color of the parent and setting the color of the child but only for those particular classes  within the parent class.

jQuery selector attempt:

```
$('.ParentClass').each(function() {
  var _thisParent = this;
   // get foreground color
   var _thisParentColor = // forecolor...
   // now apply foreground color to all elements withint parent class of particular eleemnt
   $(_thisParent .ParticularClass).each(function() {
        //error
   });
});
```

Comment: How about `$('.ParentClass .ParticularClass') ...` ??

Answer (score 4):

You can do this too:

```
$('.ParentClass .ParticularClass').css();
```

Comment: How would this allow you to access the parent's CSS and set it on the child?

Comment: @j08691 `$('.ParentClass .ParticularClass').css('color', function() { return $(this).closest('.ParentClass').css('color'); });`

Comment: @Pointy - yeah that was kind of a loaded question I asked. I knew the answer but I wanted to see Joe answer it since his answer alone isn't sufficient.

Comment: @j08691 Yes I figured; I don't like editing answers (which is probably a bad thing on my part).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ParentClass').each(function() {
   $('.ParticularClass', this).each(function() {
   });
});
```

Or

```
$('.ParentClass').each(function() {
   $(this).find('.ParticularClass').each(function() {
   });
});
```

Should do it.

Comment: So find only finds css classes under the parent class? Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `each` use `find` function

```
$('.ParentClass').find(".ParticularClass").css({....});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why instead?